# SeaBIOS, Could not boot up disk hard

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, virtualization, disk

[image]

I could not boot this up. This is Virtual Machine and I can only access to this remotely via Datto. I can only send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Atl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. How do I find libvirt?